# Rails testing - how to simulate a login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, authentication

I am a newbie to writing tests in Rails environment. I am  trying to write tests for already written code. I am trying to write a simple login test like the one shown below.

```
  test "login with invalid credentials" do
    post :login, :coach => {:user_name => 'foo', :password =>'bar'}
    assert_equals flash[:error] , "Authentication failed"
  end
```

When I try to run this test, I am expected to get an Authentication failed message. But I am getting an error instead.

```
1) Error:
test_login_with_invalid_credentials(CPControllerTest):
RS::LDAPAuthentication::ConnectionError: Net::LDAP::LdapError: Server 127.0.0.1 refused connection on port 1389.
```

This is the login method in the Application Controller

```
  def login
    self.page_title = 'Sign in'

    if logged_in? # already signed in
      session[:return_to] = nil
      redirect_to_appropriate_url
    elsif params[:coach]
      user_name, password = params[:coach][:user_name], params[:coach][:password]
      if self.current_user = User.authenticate(user_name, password) #PLACE WHERE EXCEPTION IS RAISED
        self.notice = "Signed in successfully"
        redirect_to_appropriate_url
      else
        flash[:error] = "Authentication failed"
      end
    end
    render :template => '/coach_portal/login' unless performed?
  end
```

The simple reason is the login method is trying to communicate with an external LDAP server and my test cannot connect to it. What should I do in this scenario. Should I change my code or should I simulate a LDAP connection. Even if I have simulate one, how would I do that?

Pointers/help/links much appreciated!!

Comment: are you using an authentication gem/framework?

Comment: which one? and is your LDAP server running during your tests?

Comment: The LDAP server is a custom module and it runs on an external system. My tests should be independent of the LDAP server. Whether or not a LDAP server exist, my tests should pass right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To isolate your application's behavior, I recommend stubbing out the User#authenticate method. That way, you are only testing how your application behaves when the LDAP succeeds, fails, or even raises an exception.

```
test "login with invalid credentials" do
  User.stubs(:authenticate).returns false
  post :login, :coach => {:user_name => 'foo', :password =>'bar'}
  assert_equals flash[:error] , "Authentication failed"
end
```